# Error API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED ocurred at using Youtube Data API v3

Tags: axios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

When making a request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&maxResults=5&key=<MY_API_KEY>&q=dogs
```

I get the following error response:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/119952101582",
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the http referrer of the request violates API key HTTP restrictions.

Check your API_KEY settings of your project.

You can try the request in [the documentation feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A5%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D) and see the results:

URL: `https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&type=video&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

Results:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "4Jd7oMmX6dodoqxeiB24wLkVMPY",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "CO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "ZQVJo2CIwtFFTHVA4hq4gLBld_w",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "Ci3TMqWfNLs"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-09-17T22:08:22Z",
        "channelId": "UCKTWUJqT3NSZ50I49ExjWZQ",
        "title": "Master KG - Jerusalema feat. Micro TDH &amp; Greeicy &amp; Nomcebo Zikode – [Remix] (Official Video)",
        "description": "Master KG - Jerusalema feat. Micro TDH & Greeicy & Nomcebo Zikode – [Remix] (Official Video) SUBSCRIBETE ▷ https://war.lnk.to/subscribe Ya disponible en ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ci3TMqWfNLs/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ci3TMqWfNLs/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ci3TMqWfNLs/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Warner Música",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-09-17T22:08:22Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "vgvtwWrC2W3mxKzGxE2tL8K5xC4",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "dZauWAlZwl4"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2020-12-04T00:00:08Z",
        "channelId": "UCEFNzT2RoVqGkV4e3Osyx4A",
        "title": "Piso 21 &amp; Maluma - Más De La Una (Video Oficial)",
        "description": "Piso 21 & Maluma - Más De La Una (Video Oficial) Suscríbete ahora al canal oficial de Piso 21: http://bit(.)ly/Piso21 Escucha todos los éxitos de Piso 21 aquí: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dZauWAlZwl4/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dZauWAlZwl4/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dZauWAlZwl4/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Piso 21",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2020-12-04T00:00:08Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "KUGKha-wikLcojZUG_IFiIDfqns",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "zLX_GcXt2pI"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-10-15T05:00:01Z",
        "channelId": "UC5imdbLT1yRvjbyqeHhnt0A",
        "title": "Manuel Medrano - Bajo El Agua (Video Oficial)",
        "description": "Descarga en iTunes: https://itunes.apple.com/co/album/bajo-el-agua-single/id1015028641 Adquiere en Google Play: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zLX_GcXt2pI/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zLX_GcXt2pI/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zLX_GcXt2pI/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Manuel Medrano",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2015-10-15T05:00:01Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "w6n0QzKBHByHu-HNiG8Lh3SkNUA",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "0EqHqPvXcMU"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-09-06T05:00:04Z",
        "channelId": "UCEFNzT2RoVqGkV4e3Osyx4A",
        "title": "Piso 21 &amp; Christian Nodal - Pa&#39; Olvidarme De Ella (Video Oficial)",
        "description": "No olvides suscribirte al canal de Piso 21 para ver los últimos videos musicales oficiales, audio oficial, álbumes y más! Sigue a Piso 21 en: Facebook: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0EqHqPvXcMU/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0EqHqPvXcMU/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0EqHqPvXcMU/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Piso 21",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-09-06T05:00:04Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "wHEXK_WA_JcIMFQ89iipYVAxp7U",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "W4dioKwTm1A"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-10-15T00:00:12Z",
        "channelId": "UClZuKq2m0Qu-HkopkSBLpEw",
        "title": "Lalo Ebratt, Maluma - Sukutubla (Official Video)",
        "description": "Lalo Ebratt, Maluma - Sukutubla (Official Video) Top Hits: https://smarturl.it/malumatophits My Channel: https://smarturl.it/ytmaluma Maluma: ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4dioKwTm1A/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4dioKwTm1A/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W4dioKwTm1A/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Maluma",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-10-15T00:00:12Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here:

https://answebtechnologies.in/blog/API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED/

Visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Navigate to the APIs & Services > Credentials panel in Cloud Console.

Select the name of an existing API key.

Turn off the restrictions (see screenshot)
[image]

Comment: If people find your key (which they can do very easily), you mind find some unexpected bills from Google using this approach. The reason people run into the error in the first place is because they are trying to lock down how their API key can be used and restrict to just their website and not be used/abused by the interwebs.

Comment: Actually, this practice is not correct but we can whitelist a specific domain  that's better

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. In my case I had to explicitly set the referer cURL option. I was using PHP + cURL, but there is probably an equivalent for your setup. I was scratching my head that it was empty as well and not derived by Google when it received the request. So for me I added this to my cURL request:
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.myexamplewebsite.com/");`

So in the Google API restriction console, you would have something like this:
`https://www.myexamplewebsite.com/*`

Hope this helps in your scenario.